# Count number of records returned by each group by

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a general query such as:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM Table1 AS t1
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4
```

It will return a table something similar to:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4    
data1  data2  data3  data4
data1  data2  data3  data5
data10 data11 data12 data13
data10 data11 data12 data14
data10 data11 data12 data15
```

I need to get the count for col1 to display data1 is returned twice and data10 is returned three times.  The table should look like:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   Count  
data1  data2  data3  data4  2
data1  data2  data3  data5  2
data10 data11 data12 data13 3
data10 data11 data12 data14 3
data10 data11 data12 data15 3
```

I tried count(*) in the select statement but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `OVER` clause (SQL Server 2008+):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY col1) [Count]
FROM Table1 AS t1
```

The results are:

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║  COL1  ║  COL2  ║  COL3  ║  COL4  ║ COUNT ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ data1  ║ data2  ║ data3  ║ data4  ║     2 ║
║ data1  ║ data2  ║ data3  ║ data5  ║     2 ║
║ data10 ║ data11 ║ data12 ║ data13 ║     3 ║
║ data10 ║ data11 ║ data12 ║ data14 ║     3 ║
║ data10 ║ data11 ║ data12 ║ data15 ║     3 ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2c13/1) with a demo of this.

**UPDATE**
If you need to filter based on the `COUNT` column, you can use a derived table or a CTE:

Derived Table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY col1) [Count]
        FROM Table1) A
WHERE [Count] > 2
```

CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY col1) [Count]
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE [Count] > 2
```

Results:

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║  COL1  ║  COL2  ║  COL3  ║  COL4  ║ COUNT ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ data10 ║ data11 ║ data12 ║ data13 ║     3 ║
║ data10 ║ data11 ║ data12 ║ data14 ║     3 ║
║ data10 ║ data11 ║ data12 ║ data15 ║     3 ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

[**sqlfiddle with this option**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2c13/2).

Comment: could I add a having or where clause to grab only those whose count > 2?

Comment: @Andrew Updated my answer with that filter